# Recognizing a timestamp

Tags: timestamp

I am looking at some sample data and I noticed that the transaction datetime is 42,814,662,041,308. Can anyone help me convert it please?
I have already tried converting using Epoch Unix time

Comment: Do you have any estimate for the year or years range that would have been?

Comment: What database is this? How do you obtain the value you observe? You may be trying to interpret an internal representation of the datetime value in your database as an integer.

Comment: 20th March 2017 is the date but I do not know the time.
I have just found out that 42814 is the date. How may I obtain the hour from the rest of the amount.

Comment: Again, what database is this? 42814, indeed, corresponds to 20 March 2017 in the Excel date format (number of days since 01 January 1900). But that would indicate that your date/time is concatenated together with a comma, and then "42,814" is the date part, and "662,041,308" is the time part. And because Excel's time part is the fraction of a day, 0.662041308 is 15:53:20.4. Are you sure your timestamp is stored as "42,814,662,041,308", and not as "42814.662041308"?